# ui-bootstrap datepicker not working with min and max date

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the Datepicket that is part of the AngularJS ui-bootstrap module. I'm following the tutorial / example given (see http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) but when trying to prevent users from selecting dates earlier than today or greater than 3 months from today doesn't seem to be working correctly as these are still clickable.

This is the datepicker in my view... I've written the ng-model, min-date & max-date values to the interface to make sure these are not null)

```
<datepicker ng-model="dt" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" show-weeks="false"></datepicker>
dt = {{ dt }}
minDate = {{ minDate }}
maxDate = {{ maxDate }}
```

The values are being returned....

```
dt = "2014-04-30T15:31:46.746Z" 
minDate = "2014-05-27T15:31:46.746Z"
maxDate = "2014-08-27T15:31:46.751Z"
```

this is my controller code... most of it taken from the example provided on the ui-bootstrap site

```
$scope.today = function() {
  $scope.dt = new Date();
};
$scope.today();

$scope.toggleMin = function() {
  $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
};
$scope.toggleMin();

$scope.maxDate  = new Date(new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth()+3));
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I can't see what typo or mistake I have made? I am using Chrome 34.0.1847.137 on OS X 10.9.2 so browser compatibility shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: It looks like you're getting the ISOString. This might help http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What version of Angular Bootstrap are you using? I noticed I had to upgrade to 0.11.0 to get min and max date to work. In 0.10.0, min and max date did not work for me. I had to use date-disabled instead.

Comment: We have a winner! Thanks for the answer, an upgrade has solved this issue!

Comment: Can you show me your implementation of data-disabled Imyers? Having the same issue.

Answer (score 11):

Simply use **min** and **max** attribute instead of **min-date** and **max-date** respectively in datepicker tag.

```
<input min="p.minStartDate" max="p.maxStartDate" ng-model="p.startDate" datepicker-popup="{{'dd-MM-yyyy'}}"  datepicker-options="p.dateOptions"/>
```

Comment: Not sure why this is not in the doc. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: So baffled by this...  `min-date` works just dandy in the [demo](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) and [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/204qc2fULsoG30s9cop5?p=preview) but in my app, using the same exact angular & ui-bootstrap versions, I cannot get `min-date` to work, but `min` works fine.  Good enough for now, but if anyone has insight, please lemme know.

Comment: @brandonjp: Maybe this isn't in the datepicker documentation, because this isn't a datepicker specific validator but a "normal" angular validaor. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms, they mention `min` and `max`.

Comment: `min` and `max` validate the input field. `min-date` and `max-date` control the datepicker and disable dates beyond that range.

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="text" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" 
                            ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" 
                            min="'2014-09-09'" max="'2015-06-22'"
                            datepicker-options="dateOptions" 
                            date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" 
                            ng-required="true" 
                            close-text="Close" />
```

It work for me with the angular-1.2.8 version

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the `max` or `max-date` attributes to work.

Instead, I found that I had to configure the `datepicker-options` property on the control.  [Reference here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker).

#### Template

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="d/M/yyyy" ng-model="ctrl.calendarControl.selectedDate" datepicker-options="ctrl.calendarControl.dateOptions" />
```

#### Controller

```
self.calendarControl = {
    dateOptions: {
        maxDate: new Date()
    }
};
```

Answer (score -5):

```
    $(function () {
        $("[id$=txtpaymentdate]").datepicker({
            showOn: 'button',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",

            todayBtn: "linked",
            language: "ru",
            autoclose: true

        });
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. As we can see the question has been tagged with angular js.